# What is the shelf life of Ultra Clear rice protein powder?

Tags: food-safety

I have some Ultra Clear rice protein powder that is a few years old that has never been opened and has been constantly refrigerated. Is it still safe to use? I am nervous about using it, but the current cost of the product is over $60, so I am also not happy about throwing it out. If there is a danger - then I will throw it out, and forget the cost. Otherwise, maybe I can use just a teeny bit - to test it out. I don't want to end up in the ER though. Can you please advise.

Comment: Although I can't really help you with this answer, perhaps you can be a little clearer exactly how old "a few years old" is. Years is a huge time unit. 2 years is a few years and 3 years is a few years but the 1 year difference is a lot of time.

Comment: I actually decided to throw it out, especially, since on opening up and smelling the product, it did smell a bit funny. And, to answer your question it was several years old (more than 5, I think) - and I was probably crazy to even consider it. I did find some sites that sell Ultra Clear for considerably less than $60 (like about $32) - and so I will try it again, if I feel it is a good thing. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you contact the manufacturer of the powder and ask them. You will get an answer that is specific to your product and possibly an explanation as to why the product is safe to use or not. Doing so will also help avoid any online speculation by others that may result in you becoming unnecessarily ill.

As for contacting the manufacturer, I believe that UltraClear is produced by Metagenics and you can contact them online [here](http://www.metagenics.com/contact). If that doesn't work, you can call them toll-free (more information about calling them can be found at the online contact form).